# How to limit an excerpt in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, widget

I'm using the Events Calendar by Modern Tribe in my website and I want to modify the widget.  I have everything the way I want it except for one small detail... the excerpt.  This is how the section of my code looks in my website, which pulls the events description.  But I don't want the full description for the widget... I only one 10 words or so, followed by an ellipse (...).  Any thoughts?

```
<div class="entry-content tribe-events-event-entry" itemprop="description">
    <?php if (has_excerpt ()): ?>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div> <!-- End tribe-events-event-entry -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this to create custom excerpts

```
// get the post content     
<?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
<?php
// get the first 80 words from the content and added to the $abstract variable
 preg_match('/^([^.!?\s]*[\.!?\s]+){0,80}/', strip_tags($content), $abstract);
  // pregmatch will return an array and the first 80 chars will be in the first element 
  echo $abstract[0] . '...';
    ?>
```

I adapted this from this tutorial
http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/php-generating-summary-abstract-from-a-text-or-html-string-limiting-by-words-or-sentences.html
hope it helps

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I just replaced the excerpt/content call with what you had and it works great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to your functions.php file. More info on the_excerpt can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The only follow up question I have is where do I put that?  After <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

Comment: Add it to the functions.php file in your theme. wp-content/yourthemename/functions.php

Comment: I use the excerpt elsewhere in my site so I won't want to modify it altogether.  Will this do that?

Comment: Yes, it will do that. An alternative solution is to manuall enter the excerpt in the Wordpress post. If the text box is not visible, click on screen options at the top right and confirm the excerpt is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in *function.php*

```
 
function word_count($string, $limit) {
 
$words = explode(' ', $string);
 
return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $limit));
 
}
```

Then

`<?php the_content() ?> or <?php the_excerpt() ?>` whatever you have the code replace with

this:-

```
<?php echo word_count(get_the_excerpt(), '30'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use space between a the conditional and `()`. `if (has_excerpt ()):` should be `if (has_excerpt()):`

You can just simply use

```
function pietergoosen_custom_excerpts($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), $limit, '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&hellip;' . __( 'Read more &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</a>');
}
```

and add

`<?php  echo pietergoosen_custom_excerpts($limit); ?>`

where you need to display an excerpt. Just replace `$limit` with the amount of words you would like to return.

Example to return 40 words

`<?php  echo pietergoosen_custom_excerpts(40); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

add the following code functions.php

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

MOre info on the_excerpt can be found here: http://www.happiweb.net/2014/05/gioi-han-tu-trong-mo-ta-theexcerpt-cua.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$excerpt = substr( $excerpt , 0, 100); 
echo $excerpt;
?>
```

You can change the amount to something you like by changing the 100.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to limiting the number of words in the excerpt without plugins. Add the following code to your functions.php file.

```
<?php
// Custom Excerpt 
function excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
} 
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}
?>
```

Now, instead of using the_content() or the_excerpt in your loop, use excerpt($limit) or content($limit).
If you want to limit your excerpt to 25 words the code would look like this:

```
<?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
```

I got solution to [limiting the number of words in the excerpt here](http://www.e2soft.com/forum/question/how-to-set-custom-excerpt-and-content-limit-wordpress/)

Answer (score -1):

You could use pure css and use this type of code to get an ellipsis at the end of 100px of text:

```
max-width: 100px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Interesting... didn't know this was possible.  It's working like a charm, except for the ellipsis.  Any idea?

Comment: 'code' li.tribe_events .entry-content {
 
 width: 100%;
 
 white-space: nowrap;
 
 overflow: hidden;
 
 text-overflow: ellipsis;

} 'code'